# Decoding from Binary to string into a Set splits string into chars Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, set

I have an issue. I wrote code that reads a file in binary mode (for speed) and then decodes what I have read out of the regex match into a set. The issue is that the set takes these decoded strings and turns them into chars. **If you have "14(xx) 23(WP)", the regex will get WP and xx. What is supposed to happen is that it will then take WP and xx and put it as an element in logbinset. However when it does, it turns into {'W', 'P', 'x', 'x'} instead of {"WP", "xx"} I don't have this issue when i use a list.**

However I'd like to avoid using a list because it takes in duplicates and I don't need duplicate values. Also Sets are faster to read and iterate through and i wouldn't need the extra lines of code that I'd need to ensure my list doesn't take duplicates.

W**hy is this splitting of my strings happening? I also tried taking in the binary files without decoding them but the Set converts it to an Int for whatever reason. What is goign on with my program and Python's set structure?**:

```
def odfs_bin_conversion_table_check(bintablecsv, filename):
bincsv_df = pd.read_csv(bintablecsv)
setbincsv_df = set(bincsv_df['MicronBin'])
with open(filename, "rb", buffering=102400) as lines:
    regex = re.compile(rb"\d+\((.+)\)\s+\d+\((.+)\)")
    logbinset = set()
    logbinlist = []
    missingbins = ""
    for match in filter(bool, map(regex.search, lines)):  # if search in lines, put it in match
        #logbinset.update(match.group(1))  # put matches inside logbinset
        logbinset.update((match.group(1)).decode('UTF-8','strict'))
        logbinlist.append((match.group(1)).decode())
        print(match.group(1))
        #print((match.group(1)).decode() + " " + (match.group(1)).decode()) #visual check. Can be commented out
    for x in logbinset:
        print(x)
        if x not in setbincsv_df:
            print(type(x))
            #missingbins += x.decode() + ","
    if len(missingbins) > 0:
        return missingbins[:-1] + " are not in conversion table"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `match.group(1).decode` instead of `(match.group(1)).decode`?

Comment: I don't quite understand which part of the code you are referring to in the problem description. Which variables at which points in the code correspond to `"WP"` and `{'W', 'P'}`, respectively?

Comment: @mkrieger1 that regex pattern finds strings inside paranthesis and stores them in group 1 and group 2. So if you have  "aa(xx)  23(WP)", the regex will get WP. What is supposed to happen is that it will then take WP and put it as an element in logbinset. However when it does, it turns into {'W', 'P'} instead of {"WP"}

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I thought i needed the paranthesis. I've removed them now. Made no difference

Comment: According to https://regex101.com/r/jikCUi/1, the regex in your code doesn't match the string `"aa(xx) 23(WP)"` at all. Please create a [mre].

Comment: Anyhow, `set.update` takes an iterable and inserts each element of iteration into the set. Given a string, this results in the individual characters. Maybe you meant to use `set.add` instead.

Comment: @mkrieger1 not sure what to tell you. That pattern works in my code  when I use a list. Hell when I do print statements in the code, it prints the chars. When I use that pattern in my text editors it works. I've used it in Sublime and EM editor and like I said it works in my code. The main issue is that using a set splits the words into chars.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes set.add() fixes the issue. It appears W3schools might not be the best for teaching you the intricacies of data structures. It just told me that I can use update to add multiple items. There was no mention of iterables: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp

Comment: Well, did you mean to add *multiple* items? No, you meant to add *one* item.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I meant to add group(1) and group(2). So in my original code I did logbinset.update((match.group(1)).decode(), (match.group(2)).decode()). I only took away the second element when I was debugging.  Now I have written two seperate lines:  logbinset.add(match.group(1).decode())
            logbinset.add(match.group(2).decode())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely unrelated to regular expressions or reading files in binary mode.

`set.update` treats its argument as an iterable and adds each element of the iterable to the set. Strings are an iterable, where the iteration yields the individual characters:

```
>>> for x in 'WP':
...     print(x)
W
P
```

So with `set.update`, this results in a set of characters:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.update('WP')
>>> s
{'W', 'P'}
```

To add the string `"WP"` as *one* item to a set, use the `add` method:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add('WP')
>>> s
{'WP'}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. fixed it. Gotta find a better site than w3 schools for quick references. Also not sure why that regex didn't work on that wepage you provided. I haven't changed anything and it works in my code

Comment: Maybe because `"aa(xx) 23(WP)"` is not one of the strings you are actually using.

Comment: RIght it's not. that was just an example of the top of my head *facepalm". And no it should never read something like that. Its always a number then in paranthesis any character. Thanks again for the explanation.